# Uploading Score to GameCenter, can't add two binary operands

Tags: swift, int, game-center

I'm trying to convert my time, in order to be able to upload the correct value to the Game Center. Unfortunately I get the following error:
*Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands*

Here is the code:

```
var intPart: Double = 0.0
    var fractPart: Double = modf(finalTime, &intPart)
    var isecs: Int = Int(intPart)
    var min: Int = isecs / 60)
    var sec: Int = isecs % 60)
    var hund: Int = Int(fractPart * 100)

    let time_to_send_through_game_center: __int64_t = min*6000 + (sec*100 + hund)

    sScore.value = time_to_send_through_game_center
```

The error happens in this line: 
*let time_to_send_through_game_center: __int64_t = min*6000 + (sec*100 + hund)*

Comment: The receiving variable is the type __int64_, but the calculations will be returning Int

Answer (score 1):

### Minimum Verifiable Example

First of all you should post a [Minimum Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), like this

```
let min = 1
let sec = 1
let hund = 1
let time_to_send_through_game_center: __int64_t = min * 6000 + (sec * 100 + hund)
```

### Problem

> error: binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands
>   let time_to_send_through_game_center: __int64_t = min * 6000 + (sec * 100 + hund)

### Solution

Now the problem is that the code at the right of the `=` produces and Int while you declared the left part as `__int64_t` so you can easily fix it

```
let time_to_send_through_game_center = __int64_t(min * 6000 + (sec * 100 + hund))
```

### Camels vs Snakes

Oh, in Swift we usually prefer the camel case notation

```
timeToSendThroughGameCenter
```

over the snake notation

```
time_to_send_through_game_center
```

Comment: +100 for the minimum verifiable example, I can't count how many answers I've started drafting only to answer my own question in the process of defining the question